# airflow mwaa dags, how to fetch the dag details from the environment

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, boto3, mwaa

I need to fetch the dag details like schedule frequecny from existing MWAA environment and used the below boto3 code but it was not fetching anything and any suggestion would be appriciated.`

```
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config 
sso_profile = 'admin'
environment_name = 'dev-airflow'
config = Config(region_name='us-west-2')
session = boto3.Session(profile_name=sso_profile)
mwaa_client = session.client('mwaa', config=config)
try:
    response = mwaa_client.get_environment(Name=environment_name)   
    if 'DagProcessingConfigs' not in response['Environment']:
        print("No DAGs found in the MWAA environment", response)
    else:
        dags = response['Environment']['DagProcessingConfigs']
        if not dags:
            print("No DAGs found in the MWAA environment")
        else:
            for dag in dags:
                dag_name = dag['dagId']
                schedule_interval = dag['dagProcessingConfig']['scheduleInterval']
                print(f"DAG '{dag_name}' has a schedule interval of '{schedule_interval}'")     
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

`
Code ouput sends no dag found exception eventhough there are multiple dags in that environment but the I have tried to print the response of environment and there is no "DagProcessingConfigs" parameter, not sure whether I need to enable any config parameters in to environment.

Comment: Did you get a solution to find the dag status?

Answer (score 1):

Internally using a DAG you can fetch the schedule_intervals such as below

```
    dag_lst = ['a','b','c']
    def get_dag_schedules():
        dag_schedule_lst = []
        dagbag = DagBag()
        for dag_id in dag_lst:
            if dag_id not in dagbag.dags:
                raise ValueError(f"DAG {dag_id} not found in Airflow environment")

            dag = dagbag.get_dag(dag_id)
            dag_schedule_lst.append([dag_id, dag.schedule_interval])
```